# How to use useSelector on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have following code inside my functional component.

```
const { id } = useParams();  
const categories = useSelector((state) => {
     const allCategories = state.allCategories;
     return allCategories.filter(cat => cat.id === id); 
}); 
const [code, setCode] = useState(categories.length === 1 ? categories[0].code : '');
```

However this code runs correctly only once. Then if I refresh the page, it doesn't work. Please help me to fix this issue. Also, if this is against best practices, please let me know the correct way to do this.
Actual use case is, there is a category table and user clicks on "edit category" and then I navigate to this component to display the current data (ie: category code). Since, the category table already has data, allCategories is filled

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you mean by doesn't work when you refresh the page?

Comment: Where does the `allCategories` part of the state get filled? Only way I can see this issue occur is if you navigate to a route/component which fills in `allCategories` and then you go to this component. Yet if you reload, it doesn't have the `allCategories` state so it doesn't work.

Comment: My guess is that `state.allCategories` is set by dispatching an action so you should dispatch that action in an effect. If they are fetched asynchronously then you should add loading and error meta data so you can show the result of the async action.

Comment: @szczocik Doesn't work means that the category code is not set to "code" state variable

Comment: @ljbc1994 `allCategories` is in redux state. It is get filled by a back-end API call. Actual use case is, there is a category table and user clicks on "edit category" and then I navigate to this component to display the current data (ie: category code). Since, the category table already has data, `allCategories` is filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the data is changed in some other place of the program its prolematic to use it as a default state value...
instead bind the value with `useEffect()`

```
const { id } = useParams();  
const categories = useSelector((state) => {
     const allCategories = state.allCategories;
     return allCategories.filter(cat => cat.id === id); 
}); 
const [code, setCode] = useState(''); 
useEffect(()=>{
    if(categories.length === 1)
        setCode(categories[0].code)
},[categories.length&&categories[0].?code])
```

NOTE: the code will be set like so whenever `categories[0].code` is changed...

Comment: Thanks a lot. `useEffect` fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like redux-persist to save the redux state to local storage or to another storage system

Comment: Does redux state get destroyed when page refresh?